# Run Python project for Brain Extraction downloaded from GitHub

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to run a Python project downloaded from GitHub. That's the project https://github.com/iitzco/deepbrain. It's a software to extract brains from MRI.

I followed the guide, installing Python and then running:

```
$ pip install deepbrain
```

But if I write:

```
deepbrain-extractor -h
```

on the Windows 10 command line(cmd) I get:

```
deepbrain-extractor is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run `extractor.py` you should change your directory in `\deepbrain` and run this command `python extractor.py`